# How to make a weekday field and time-of-day field that are not actual dates?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access that lists all classes at a school. I'm trying to create a field that indicates what day of week class meets (Monday, Tuesday, etc), and another field for what time of day the class starts (2:30 pm etc.). I shouldn't have to input an actual calendar date, because these values stand for a schedule that occurs weekly. It seems my only option is to use a text field? Surely this has been solved a thousand times. What would be best practice for this type of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some arbitrary date this has the first weekday of your weeks.

Add one day for every subsequent weekday, and apply the format *dddd* to display the weekday name.

Apply a time part as needed, and set the format when displaying the values to *Short Time* or similar.